# Nativescript no elements in "Inspect Element" tab while debugging

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

When I run tns debug ios, after "Backend socket created" it throws following error

```
assertion failed: 16G29 15A8401: libxpc.dylib + 69578 [CBE96042-79D0-3515-8570-968B28E72519]: 0x7d
```

The debugger opens and app runs as it should, but in the inspect element tab there is no content. I have reinstalled my entire OS and installed nothing but nativescript and still get this error. Same result if I use --chrome in the chrome dev tools

Also I can run the app on android, no error there, but still nothing in the inspect panel. So maybe my missing elements are not related to this error at all, but what else would cause an empty inspect panel?

Any ideas?

Comment: I am seeing a similar issue with the react native debugger where is won't open at all, but I get the same error in the console from ios.  In works fine on android.  This just began today without any code changes (I wonder if it's due to the xcode command line tools update)

Comment: I'm having the same trouble. I can't get the element panel to show the ui elements. I wonder if this happened with a nativescript release, because I have seen youtube videos showing it working.